# Windows command line get last column

Tags: regex, windows, command-line

I am trying to print / cut the last column from the following command

```
ipconfig |findstr "Default Gateway"
```

Q1 How does one accomplish this in Windows command line interface without installing projects like cygwin?

Also because i got a few VMware machines installed i get multiple default gateways that are empty.

Q2 Is it possible to create a regex in Windows that only prints the last column / columns containing the syntax of an actual IP address. Excluding the empty columns and the :: column.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`findstr` accepts `/r` option which make the string to be treated as a regular expression:

The lines you want to get are ends with digit; you can use following pattern:

```
[0-9]$
```

---

```
ipconfig | findstr "Default Gateway" | findstr /r "[0-9]$"
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me in the right direction. Is their also a way to cut out the last column of the output?

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk, `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %F in ('ipconfig ^| findstr "Default Gateway" ^| findstr /r "[0-9]$"') do @echo %~F`

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk, Or `for /f "tokens=13 delims= " %F in ('ipconfig ^| findstr "Default Gateway" ^| findstr /r "[0-9]$"') do @echo %~F`

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk, `for .... in ('command') do process` will process output of command line by line.

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk, `/f "option" %f` specifies to extract a field according to `option`.

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk, For more information, please see this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

As a Windows batch file:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %%a IN ('ipconfig^|findstr /L /c:"Default Gateway"') DO FOR /f "tokens=*" %%d IN ("%%a") DO IF NOT "%%d"=="" ECHO(%%d

GOTO :EOF
```

---

For directly-from-the-prompt:

cls&setlocal&@FOR /f "tokens=2*delims=:" %a IN ('ipconfig^|findstr /L /c:"Default Gateway"') DO @FOR /f "tokens=*" %d IN ("%a") DO @IF NOT "%d"=="" ECHO(%d

Comment: What if you do it directly in the CLI without batch?